# Separate output with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry for the misleading title but I don't know a better expression for it. I am trying to create a XSL which provides 2 different main sections in my output XML for completely different types of data. However, I always get BOTH types of data in EACH template call. I hope you can give me a hint how to achieve this. These are my ingredients:

Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <books>
        <book>Xpages</book>
        <book>XML</book>
    </books>

    <dvds>
        <dvd>Star Wars</dvd>
        <dvd>Prometheus</dvd>
    </dvds>
</root>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <media>
            <xsl:element name="booklist">
                <xsl:call-template name="books"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="dvdlist">
                <xsl:call-template name="dvds"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </media>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="books" match="books">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvds" match="dvds">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="books/book" name="book">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dvds/dvd" name="dvd">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<media>
    <booklist>
        Xpages
        XML    
        Star Wars
        Prometheus    
    </booklist>
    <dvdlist>
        Xpages
        XML    
        Star Wars
        Prometheus
    </dvdlist>
</media>
```

But this is what I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<media>
    <booklist>
        Xpages
        XML
    </booklist>
    <dvdlist>
        Star Wars
        Prometheus
    </dvdlist>
</media>
```

As you can see it doubles my 2 lists. I guess it's because I use apply-templates inside the two templates but there must be a way to solve this. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start off by doing `xsl:call-template`, but within that the `<xsl:apply-templates />` will select all nodes. At this point you are still positioned on the document node. What actually happens is XSLT's built-in templates apply, which first selects the `root` node, and then, because you have no template for this, it will select both the `books` and `dvds` nodes.

What you need to do is simply target the nodes you are interested in.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <media>
            <xsl:element name="booklist">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/books" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="dvdlist">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="root/dvds" />
            </xsl:element>
        </media>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="books/book" name="book">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dvds/dvd" name="dvd">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that appy-templates also can have a select attribute.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be this XSL-template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <media>
            <xsl:element name="booklist">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="books/book" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="dvdlist">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="dvds/dvd" />
            </xsl:element>
        </media>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dvd">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<media><booklist>
        Xpages
        XML
    </booklist>
    <dvdlist>
        Star Wars
        Prometheus
    </dvdlist>
</media>
```

Comment: Thank you - I upvoted your answer though I accepted the other one because it was earlier ;-)